# Did Sumerian have /ħ/?

Tags: phonology, sumerian, akkadian

According to [Gelb 1961](https://oi.uchicago.edu/sites/oi.uchicago.edu/files/uploads/shared/docs/mad2.pdf), the famous Sumerian sign É ("house, building") was originally pronounced `/ħa/` (or *ḥa* in Semiticist transcription). The main evidence for this is loanwords into other languages: É.GAL ("temple", literally "great house") > Hebrew *hēkhāl*, Aramaic *hēkhəlā*, Arabic *haykal*. The pronunciation would then have shifted to `/e/` through dissimilation and pharyngeal loss (both of which are well-attested in Akkadian and seem to be widely accepted).

However, this source is half a century old, and I haven't seen any mention of `/ħ/` in more recent discussions of Sumerian (like Foxvog's grammar).

Is it generally believed nowadays that Sumerian had an `/ħ/`-like phoneme, which doesn't show up in Akkadian due to the famous loss of pharyngeals? If so, are there any other signs whose Sumerian values should be reinterpreted as a result (like the Sumerian word for "house" being ḤA instead of É)? And if not, how do modern scholars explain the loans like *hēkhāl*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question.
On the whole, Sumerologists read Sumerian thru the window of Babylonian phonetics. Quite clearly, this means that Sumerian as per Sumerology is *not* genuine Sumerian.
I've been working on reconstructing the real phonetics of Sumerian. It seems that Sumerian had two "secret" laryngeals, not just ḥ which is e-coloring, but also h which is not e-coloring.
Extremely archaic cuneiform like that of Eblaite shows that MA2 "boat" was probably *mah and A2 "arm" was probably *ah.
Sometimes the "secret" laryngeals of Sumerian are visible in the other languages, as you mention with the case of É.GAL which was probably pronounced *ḥay-kal, which also gives Hurrian haikalli "palace".

Comment: Very interesting! Do let me know if you publish or release something on this.

Comment: One quick follow-up—do you agree with Gelb that A2, E3, I3, U3 also had an onset (distinct from E2's /ħ/) that disappeared in Akkadian use? And if so, what do you reconstruct that onset as? (Your mention of A2 as *ah implies otherwise, but I want to check.)

Comment: In the case of I3 vs i, it seems that i3 was 'i (aleph i) while i was ḥi (heth i)  u3 was 'u. These signs did not have the same initial.

Answer (score 3):

[Jagersma](https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A2961989/view) agrees with Gelb that Sumerian had "hidden" phonemes `/h/` and `/ʔ/`, but disagrees about `/ħ/`.

He points out that transcriptions of É (or É.GAL) generally use `/h/`, even in languages where `/ħ/` was available: see the Hebrew, Arabic, and Aramaic loans mentioned in the question, but also Hurrian *haikalli* (mentioned by Fournet) and Ugaritic *hkl*. Based on this, he reconstructs a pronunciation `/haj/`; the later reading as `/e/` comes not from Akkadian dissimilation, but from simplification of diphthongs. (See also the early Akkadian loan *ayyakku* < **hayyanaku* < É.AN.NA(K) `/haj ʔanak/`.)

According to [Hasselbach](https://www.academia.edu/37493785/Sargonic_Akkadian_A_Historical_and_Comparative_Study_of_the_Syllabic_Texts), it's true that the sign É is used for `/ħa~ħe/` in Sargonic cuneiform; she attributes this not to a Sumerian `/ħ/`, but to diphthong coalescence. Since the classic Akkadian dissimilation of `/a/` to `/e/` near pharyngeals was already starting to take place, it would make sense for Akkadian scribes to use the sign `/haj~he/` (É) for the H that triggered the dissimilation and the sign `/ha/` (Á) for the H that didn't.

> If so, are there any other signs whose Sumerian values should be reinterpreted as a result (like the Sumerian word for "house" being ḤA instead of É)?

Many. For a few examples, Jagersma reads Á as *ha*, MÁ as *maʔ*, and AN as *ʔan*, though he notes that it's difficult to tell the difference between `/ʔ/` and `/h/` without the help of foreign loans (since they both disappeared fairly early, and are mostly visible indirectly by how they trigger postconsonantal forms of suffixes and preconsonantal forms of prefixes).