# What are good references on Eblaite cuneiform?

Tags: reference-request, cuneiform, akkadian

According to [Wikipedia's article on the Eblaite language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eblaite_language#Phonological_system):

> Studying the usage context for the symbols I, I<sub>2</sub>, A, ʾA, ḪA, etc. with regard to the writing conventions of Akkadian scribes enabled the determination, beyond some identification difficulties created by the graphical barrier, of "the existence and autonomy of the phonemes /h/, /ḥ/, and /ḫ/ confirmed by the realization of the vowel /a/ as [ɛ] in the closed syllables /ḥaC/ and /ʾaC/, as well as the tendency to extend this phenomenon to the vowel /a/ followed by a pharyngeal. It is currently lacking the elements to determine the existence of a phoneme /ġ/ or a variant [ġ]."
>
> Also through a contextual analysis of the symbols z + Vowel (V): ze<sub>2</sub>, s + V: se<sub>11</sub>, š + V, Pelio Fronzaroli confirmed the existence of the phonemes /s/, /ṣ/, /ḍ/, and /ẓ/, as well as the phonemes /s/, /š/, and /ṯ/, a group to which it is perhaps also necessary to add /z/.

I find this intriguing, and am curious to know more (for example, what alternate readings should we assign to these signs based on this, and [what can this tell us about Sumerian](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/38656/10559)?).

However, I haven't been able to find a good overview of Eblaite cuneiform; it usually seems to be mentioned as a sort of afterthought attached to Akkadian, with the writing system summarized as "we really don't know enough to say". Wikipedia cites Fronzaroli 1978 and 1980, but unfortunately I don't speak French well enough to understand technical works.

Where can I read more about this, preferably in English? Alternately, what is the state of the art here, if it can be summed up in the span of an answer?

Comment: *I don't speak French well enough to understand technical works.* - Use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com).

Comment: @Lucian Google Translate works well enough for day-to-day things, but tends to struggle with technical vocabulary. I wouldn't expect its training data to include in-depth discussion of cuneiform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wikipedia page on Eblaite is unfortunately full of garbage. Many claims are outrageously false.
I have personally written a book on Eblaite cuneiform and lexicon:
https://www.thebookedition.com/fr/lions-d-urkesh-et-cuneiforme-eblaite-p-125021.html
Originally, I wanted to know if Hurrian cuneiform had anything to do with Eblaite.
My book summarizes the (best and clearest) data listed in Hafouz's dissertation:
https://www.db-thueringen.de/receive/dbt_mods_00024086